# Stylus `middleware` throws error and not generating `css` file

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

I am getting this error on run of my `stylus` using connect server. I am not getting final out put as `.css` file here.

error:

```
D:\Projects\TCP\node_modules\stylus\lib\renderer.js:187
  this.options.paths.push(path);
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Renderer.include (D:\Projects\TCP\node_modules\stylus\lib\renderer.js:187
:21)
    at Renderer.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\TCP\node_modules\nib\lib\nib.js:51:11)
    at Renderer.use (D:\Projects\TCP\node_modules\stylus\lib\renderer.js:203:6)
    at Object.compile (D:\Projects\TCP\server.js:12:55)
    at D:\Projects\TCP\node_modules\stylus\lib\middleware.js:152:31
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

My Server.js:

```
var connect =   require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
    nib = require('nib'),
    stylus = require('stylus');

var app = connect();

app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src     : __dirname + '/public',
    force   : true,
    compile : function compile(str, path) {
                return stylus(str, path).set('filename', path).use(nib());
            }
}));

app.use(serveStatic("public"));
app.listen(5000, function () {console.log("HI", __dirname);}); //works!
```

`.style` file at `public/css/tcp.styl` - out put can be the same place. what is the issue here? how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because of this line:

```
return stylus(str, path).set('filename', path).use(nib());
```

Second argument of the `stylus` call should be an object with options not a string with path. In your case the call should be just `stylus(str)`.